# Passing data to interceptors before sending requests and/or replies

Tags: c#, wcf, interceptor

I'm currently working with message interceptors and I'd like to pass data from my service methods to interceptors (i.e. to BeforeSendRequest and BeforeSendReply). However, I can't figure out how to do this.

What I did so far is I have static variables that I set during the service execution and then fetch when the interceptors execute. This work fine except if multiple messages are sent at the same time, one of them will overwrite the values of others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example is to use message properties:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace SO21299236
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var address = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/" + Guid.NewGuid());
            var service = new ServiceHost(typeof (MyService));
            var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
            var ep = service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), binding, address);
            ep.Behaviors.Add(new MyBehavior() );
            service.Open();

            var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(address));
            var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
            proxy.DoSomething();

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }

    internal class MyBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }
    }

    internal class CustomMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            var prop = reply.Properties.FirstOrDefault(z => z.Key == "MyProperty");
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Value);
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoSomething();
    }

    class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add("MyProperty", 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties` is working just great! Thanks.